# Partition of unity. Does this one exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, compact-manifolds

Let $X:=\mathbb{R^n}$ be given and $M \subset X$ be a compact set in it. Then my question is: Are there $\alpha_i \in C^{\infty}(X,\mathbb{R})$ such that $supp(\alpha_i) \subset N$, where $N$ is an epsilon surrounding of $M$, such that those $\alpha_i$ form a partition of unity on M?

Comment: What do you mean by partition of unity for functions whose values are in $X$?

Comment: that means that there sum at every point on $M$ is always equal to one.

Comment: Right, but then your functions would have to take real values, not values in $X$.

Comment: Even with real values, there is something odd here. It seems that you can use just a single $a_i$ which is $1$ on $M$ and has support in $N$. If nothing more is desired, the problems appears trivial.

Comment: it is not $C^{\infty}$ on X

Comment: @brom you're totally right.

Answer (score 0):

As Harald Hanche-Olsen [said](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609107/partition-of-unity-does-this-one-exist#comment1282966_609107), one $\alpha_i$ is enough. Let $E$ be the $\epsilon/3$ neighborhood of $M$. Convolve $\chi_{E}$ with a $C^\infty$ bump function $\phi$ such that $$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \phi=1\quad \text{and}\quad \operatorname{supp}\phi\subset \{x:|x|<\epsilon/3\}$$ 
The convolution $\chi_E*\phi$ is $C^\infty$-smooth, is equal to $1$ on $M$, and its support is contained in $N$.