# The unsolved extension problem on manifolds.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

I have been struggeling for quite a while with this problem:

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact $C^k-$ submanifold and $\phi_i: B_i(0) \rightarrow M$ be the associated set of charts $(\phi_i)_{i \in \{1,...,n\}}$, where $B_i(0)$ is an open ball around $0$, such that $\phi_i(B_i(0)) \subset M$ is relatively open. Now we call a function $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ k-times continuously differentiable if for every chart $f \circ \phi_i$ is k-times continuously differentiable.

Now I am supposed to show that there is a map $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is k-times continuously differentiable and $F|_M = f$ such that $\text{supp(F)} \subset N$, where N is an epsilon-surrounding of M.

What have I tried so far: My first idea was to use a partition of unity, as we only have a continuously differentiable function $f$ via $f \circ \phi_i$, but this did not really work. Further, my problem was how to make the transition from $M$, where it is pretty clear, what $F$ does to $N$, which is outside from $M$ and hence completely undefined.

I appreciate any kind of help and suggestion, also if you cannot offer a complete solution.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you extend $f$ to a neighbourhood $N$ of $M$ that should roughly look like $M\times (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)^{n-d}$. Then you take a ($C^\infty$) cutoff-function $\varphi$ that is $\equiv 1$ on $M$ and has support in $N$. Then you can extend the cut-off $\varphi\cdot F_N$ trivially (by $0$) to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

To get the first extension, you get local extensions and glue them together using a partition of unity.

Since $M$ is a $C^k$ submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, every $m\in M$ has a neighbourhood $U_m$ such that there exists a $C^k$-diffeomorphism $\psi_m \colon U_m \to (-\delta_m,\delta_m)^n$ that maps $U_m \cap M$ to $(-\delta_m,\delta_m)^d\times \{0\}$ ($d$ is the dimension of $M$). You can trivially extend $f$ to $U_m$ by declaring it independent of the last $n-d$ coordinates in the chart $\psi$. That is the local extension. Since $M$ is compact, it is covered by finitely many of the $U_m$, and then you glue the local extensions to $U_1,\,\dotsc,\, U_r$ together with a partition of unity.

Comment: okay, understood the last part, but I do not know any function $\phi$ that is $1$ on $M$ and has support in N. ( I guess there are some typical examples of such functions.) And how do you extend a function $f$ that is only given on M?

Comment: Your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609107/partition-of-unity-does-this-one-exist) is about exactly that situation (the cut-off).

Comment: yes, but the person who has answered there, did not write down the function explicetly atoo.

Comment: Regarding the extension of $f$. Is it clear (not in detail, but in principle) how one extends it to the $U_m$?

Comment: @Lipschitz Explicitly, you can only hope to get something when you have an explicit embedded $M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Abstractly, all you can work with is "there is this and that that I can use, done".

Comment: never heard of this kind of function( we also never talked about convolution in class), so it means that I'll have to go through a lot of proofs just for this particular homework. Your $U_m$ is not just the image of one chart right, but it is rather an actual open neighbourhood in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of one particular point of my manifold $M$? So I extend it by looking at $f \circ \psi_m$ and throw n-d coordinates away?( By the way: In class we only said that there is a diffeomorphism $\psi:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ that does what your $\psi_m$ does.

Comment: Right, exactly that. You use the $\psi_m$ to project a small neighbourhood of a part of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto $M$, and use that projection to extend $f$ locally.

Comment: okay and regarding the thing with the cutoff function? I try to understand what this guy in the other thread meant: I thought about a function like $\phi(x):=e^{\frac{\epsilon^2}{x^2-\epsilon^2}}$ and 0 if we are not in $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$. Then I would look at the convolution $ \chi_{(U_1 \cup...\cup U_m) \cap M} \cdot \phi$. How do I see that this one does it? What are the particular properties of a convolution that are important here?

Comment: Not exactly that, actually. For the convolution, you need a function that is nonzero on a set of positive measure. $N = U_1 \cup \dotsc \cup U_r$ is a neighbourhood of $M$, so there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that the $\varepsilon$.neighbourhood of $M$ is contained in $N$. Then you use for example $\chi_A$, where $A$ is the $\varepsilon/3$-neighbourhood of $M$. It's nothing that is adequately taught in the comments here, that should be taught in one of your courses, analysis on manifolds, or differential geometry, if it wasn't treated in analysis.

Comment: well, I am currently doing Analysis (have not heard analysis on manifolds or differential geometry yet). so if this convolution thing is too tough for me, is there another way to do this?

Comment: @Lipschitz If you have something concrete given, you can usually use more concrete constructions. If you work with something abstract, you only need to be able to say "that's how it works". If you haven't yet treated convolutions, that's of course a problem. But everything you need is to know the existence of a sufficiently smooth partition of unity, or sufficiently smooth cut-off functions (which follows from partitions of unity). Have you any theorems about the existence of smooth partitions of unity?

Comment: okay, I will check that( we had one that may be applicable here when we proved Gauß's theorem). But I have a question regarding your $\psi_m$. Actually I think I was wrong about this. We cannot look at $f \circ \psi_m$ even if we throw away the last coordinates of the map $\psi_m$ because this map does not map into M which is the domain of f. Cause the image of $\psi_m$ with throwing away the last coordinate is just some subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and it is even impossible to project this set into $M$ by using $\phi_m : U_\epsilon (0) \subset \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow M$. I am confused

Comment: It is impossible to use $f \circ \phi_m \circ \psi_m$ cause we don't know that the image(with throwing away coordinates) of $\psi$ is a subset of the $\phi 's$ domain.

Comment: Ah, right, $f \circ \psi_m^{-1}$. Or, more precisely, $f \circ \psi_m^{-1}\circ \pi$, where $\pi$ is the projection onto the first $d$ coordinates. So $\psi_m^{-1}$ maps the image of $\pi$ into $M$.

Comment: but how is this construction different from saying: Just take m charts $\phi_m$ that cover the manifold and define $f \circ \phi_m \circ \pi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\pi$ is your projection. Why is it necessary to introduce your map?

Comment: Ah, because I forgot to finally again compose with $\psi_m$. You could also use $f\circ\phi_m\circ\pi\circ\psi_m$ (note that $\phi_m$ is basically the same as $\psi_m^{-1}$ restricted to the first $d$ coordinates). You need the $\psi_m$ to transport it back to $U_m$, the actual open set at the manifold.

Comment: okay, now I am fine. thank you....